# VB5 and VB6 will not respond to WinMove

Tags: autohotkey

I have tried every combination of the below and nothing seems to work for VB5 or VB6 on Windows 8. Can anyone please help?

```
#z::
Run, "C:\Program Files XP\VB50\vb5.exe"
;Run, "C:\Program Files XP\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98\VB6.EXE"
;SetTitleMatchMode 2
;WinWait Microsoft Visual Basic
WinWait, ahk_class wndclass_desked_gsk
WinActivate
WinMove, 200, 500
return
```

The app opens, but I cannot get it to move. I need to move VB5 to position 1920, 0 on my second monitor. But it won't respond to 200, 500.

Comment: Is this using AutoHotkey?

Comment: are you sure the window is named Microsoft Visual Basic, maybe the spaces provide a problem? Another possible problem: when my VB starts it shows a dialog to show a new project. While that dialog is open i cannot move the window, so maybe WinMove can't move it either